Set rds endpoint as an environment variable to Elastic Beanstalk in terraform
I have the following terraform script which creates Elastic Beanstalk  with rds:
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "elb_app" {
  name = "my-app"

}


resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "elb_env" {
  name                = "my-env"
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.elb_app.name
  solution_stack_name = data.aws_elastic_beanstalk_solution_stack.net_latest.name
  
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "RDS_HOSTNAME"
    value     = #  How can I set here the RDS endpoint ???
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "HasCoupledDatabase"
    value     = "true"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBEngine"
    value     = var.db_engine
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBEngineVersion"
    value     = var.db_engine_version
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBInstanceClass"
    value     = var.db_instance_type
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBPassword"
    value     = var.db_password
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:rds:dbinstance"
    name      = "DBUser"
    value     = var.db_user
  }
 }

The question is: how can I set the RDS_HOSTNAME ?
As far as I know, it is possible to  get the endpoint from an RDS created as a separate resource, but I didn't find any documentation how to get this from RDS created as part of an Elastic Beanstalk.
I spent many days and didn't find any example however it should be a typical case for developers.

Do you want that beanstalk to create the RDS or do you have a pre existing  RDS?

@JRichardsz is it not clear from the script?

I don't understand why you need the hostname if it will be created and injected automatically

I have not tried it but according to the docs, these env variables are injected automatically by the elastic bean stalk:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-nodejs.rds.html#nodejs-rds-connect

Adding a DB instance takes about 10 minutes. When the environment update is complete, the DB instance's hostname and other connection information are available to your application through the following environment properties:


To validate it, you can create manually env environment with and RDS, then perform one of these validations:

Using the UI, go to the configuration and check if these variables exist



Using the shell, enter to the ec2 and execute env.
From the inside of your application, at the entrypoint print the env variables


Thanks, this is exactly what I looked for. Will read the documentation more careful next time.

It looks like you have a pre-existing RDS. You can try creating an SSM parameter with a name like rds_host and store the host value in this param. Then you can refer it at the time of creating your cloudformation stack like this.
'{{resolve:ssm:parameter-name:version}}'

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html
